# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkAppBundleResourcesAction

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to create an appbundle for my Flutter app. It's been working nice until now, but  for some reason it's giving an error now. I just went to the project's folder and ran `flutter clean` and then `flutter build appbundle`. Nonetheless, it gave the following error:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in quotes...                           2.060ms

 Building with sound null safety

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkBundleReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkAppBundleResourcesAction
   > java.nio.file.FileSystemAlreadyExistsException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 43s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            105,0s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hey @Antonio Peña Did you found a solution? I am stuck with this issue now.

Comment: Yes, although I don't remember what to do exactly. In the solution to this issue are mentioned some possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the bug, although don't remember exactly how. Here are some of the things I did, ordered by level of importance (the most likely answer it at the top).

### **1. Configure your `packagingOptions`**

Go to your `android/app/build.gradle` and add the following snippet of code at the end of your `android {...}`:

```
android {

    // Some stuff...

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

}
```

### **2. Check `buildTypes`**

Once again, in your `android/app/build.gradle`, at `android {...}`, you should have a `buildscript {...}` inside. If not, add it. If added, revise it has the same values for the following properties (`packagingOptions` from the first point added):

```
android {

    // Some stuff...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

}
```

### **3. Update multidex**

Inside of your `android/app/build.gradle` as well, update the multidex you have at `dependencies {...}`. It'd also be great to update any other implementation you have there, but the important one is multidex. This is mine:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

If you don't have `dependencies {...}` in your file, add it at the end.

### **4. Another dependencies upgrade**

This time it's in the other gradle file. The route is `android/build.gradle`, and you just have to enter in the `buildscript {...}` and update what you find in `dependencies {...}`. In my case:

```
buildscript {

    // Some stuff...

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

### **5. Increase the value of your `org.gradle.jvmargs`**

This is how much can your builder take of memory to run the bundle's generation. The higher, the better, although it has to be lower than your computer/laptop's RAM and doesn't need to be really big. I have a laptop of 8 GB RAM and it goes without any error with the following configuration:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

That's a bit more than half of the RAM's power. `4608M` = 4.608 GB!

Why did I choose it? Random. It was of only `1204M` or so before changing it.